# how to delete or modify the linkedin cookies value using java?

Tags: java, cookies, linkedin-api

How to reset the linkedin cookies in the browser through java, I am using socialauth to login to linkedin and the linkedin session maintains outside the application scope also.

So I want to clear the linkedin session which are in browser so that the session is not maintained.

Please help me how to clear the cookie or reset the linkedin cookies in java.

Regards
Tony

Comment: Do you have access to the cookie?  If the cookie is not registered on the domain your webapp is running I don't think you can do anything with the cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution might be to load the [LinkedIn API JavaScript library](https://developer.linkedin.com/javascript) code, and then call the `IN.User.logout(callbackFunction, callbackScope)` function:

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/inauth-inevent-and-inui

Comment: i just want to get user profile and the connections the user has.  so that i use java. If i use these java script will i be able to get all the information i mentioned?

Comment: You can use the LinkedIn APIs using either of Java or JavaScript - it really depends on what you want to do. You can retrieve the connections via JavaScript and then process/display them to the user, and can communicate as needed via AJAX with the server.